# SAPUI5 batch submit returns error

Tags: sapui5

I am using the following code, in an attempt to batch upload the changes made on a table:

```
onConfirmActionPressed: function() {
    var oModel = this.getModel();

    oModel.setUseBatch(true);

    oModel.submitChanges();
}
```

I am using `setProperty()` to set the new values, like this:

```
onSingleSwitchChange: function(oControlEvent) {
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    var rowBindingContext = oControlEvent.getSource().getBindingContext();

    oModel.setProperty(rowBindingContext.sPath + "/Zlspr", "A");
}
```

When `onConfirmActionPressed` is executed, I get a server error, saying that "Commit work during changeset processing not allowed" on SAP R3.

When I upload the lines of the table one-by-one, it works fine. However, uploading this way is very slow, and in some cases it takes more than 10 minutes for the process to complete.

Am I doing something wrong while batch submitting? Is there a chance the issue is due to server (R3) misconfiguration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override methods:
/IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~CHANGESET_BEGIN
/IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~CHANGESET_END

Keep track of the errors across all calls to update methods and if everything went OK then in changeset_end perform commit on the database

---

edit:

To clarify:

In your Data Provider Class Extension in SAP Gateway you need to find your **YOURENTITY_UPDATE_ENTITY** method and get rid off any COMMIT WORK statements.

Then you need to redefine **/IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~CHANGESET_BEGIN** method and, which is a method which is fired before any batch operation. You could define a class attribute such as table *mt_batch_errors* which would be emptied in this method.

When you post batch changes from UI5 using *oModel.submitChanges()* all single changes to Entities are directed to appropriate ..._UPDATE_ENTITY methods. You need to keep track of any possible errors and if any occurs then fill your *mt_batch_errors* table.

After all entities have been updated **/IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~CHANGESET_END** method is fired in which you are able to check *mt_batch_errors* table if any errors occurred during the batch process. If there were errors then you should probably **ROLLBACK WORK**, and if not then you are free to **COMMIT WORK**.

That is just an example of how it could be done, I'm curious of other suggestions.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was very useful.